# NSURLSession label not changing text swift xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to use NSURLSession to get data from a website and display it in the label.  The data is displaying in my `println` and the background is changing color based on the data but does not print the data in the label.  Thanks in advance for the help!

The following code is in my viewDidLoad() function:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            if urlContent!.containsString("<div class=\"currentStatus warning\">") {

            var contentArray = urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("warning\">")

            var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</div>")

            var statusNS = newContentArray[0] as NSString

            var stat = newContentArray[0] as String

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                println(stat)

                self.statusLabel.text = stat

                if statusNS.containsString("closed") {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                } else {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                }

            })

            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Hmm...Can't seem to find out"
                }
            }

        }

        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `statusLabel` is correctly connected in Interface Builder. If you log the value of the status label, you will likely find `nil`.

Comment: It seems to be correctly connected because if I put `self.statusLabel.text = "Hello World"`it will show Hello World as the text

Comment: If you set the text in "stat" just after the println statement confirms it is not empty, you should see the expected text. Maybe something else is overwriting the text again just after that?

Comment: I've tried everything and can't figure out why it's not working, I tested with `self.statusLabel.text = "f" + stat + "g"` and only the f displayed on the screen